# my pipenv doesnt create a pipfile and pipfile.lock in any of my projects folders anymore

Tags: python, django, python-requests, pipenv, pipfile

It used to automatically create these files in the folder I was working in, in the command line. If I were to say install django...

```
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Djangoproj>pipenv install django
Installing django…
Adding django to Pipfile's [packages]…
Installation Succeeded
Installing dependencies from Pipfile.lock (536933)…
  ================================ 9/9 - 00:00:02
To activate this project's virtualenv, run pipenv shell.
Alternatively, run a command inside the virtualenv with pipenv run.
```

This is what I get. I have an empty folder. I dont get the pipfile or pipfile.lock like I am supposed to. Has anyone encountered this before? Is there a solution to this? I have already uninstalled pipenv and reinstalled the package a few times already. Same thing goes for installing requests package.

```
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Djangoproj>pipenv install requests
Installing requests…
Adding requests to Pipfile's [packages]…
Installation Succeeded
Installing dependencies from Pipfile.lock (536933)…
  ================================ 9/9 - 00:00:02
To activate this project's virtualenv, run pipenv shell.
Alternatively, run a command inside the virtualenv with pipenv run.

C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Djangoproj>dir
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is 206B-FC0C

 Directory of C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Djangoproj

04/27/2020  03:37 AM    <DIR>          .
04/27/2020  03:37 AM    <DIR>          ..
               0 File(s)              0 bytes
               2 Dir(s)  83,042,668,544 bytes free
```

still nothing in it

Comment: Have you tried upgrading `pipenv`, in case it's a bug in the version you're using?

Comment: C:\Users\Admin>pipenv --version
pipenv, version 2018.11.26

C:\Users\Admin>

Answer (score 1):

I solved it, I have no idea why it works like this but for some reason pipenv will not make the 2 files in the root directory folder.

C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\practicepipenv\pipenv>

So i made the 'pipenv' directory within the root 'practicepipenv' and ran 'pipenv install django'  in the 'pipenv' directory and it created the pipfiles.